# lm-sensors / psensor shows very high readings for temp5 & temp6 compared to other sensors

Tags: overheating, fan, temperature, lm-sensors

[Psensor Readings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xfxh5.png)

[*Details* about temp sensors upon clicking *Preferences*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TYnyk.png)

I am using Ubuntu 20.04LTS in Thinkpad L380 Yoga. Recently I faced some overheating issues during laptop charging. So I installed lm-Sensors and was observing the readings for last 4-5 days. Temp5 and Temp6 (I don't know what they are representing) displays around 111 deg Centigrade most of the times. Is it normal ? If not, then what should be the normal range and what is the problem occuring in my laptop ? Also, fan1 sensor is showing 0RPM(!). Kindly help me. (Screenshot attached)

Comment: Did you also run `sudo sensors-detect` and install any required modules?

Comment: Right-click on one of the temperatures and select `Preferences` this can show a bit more information such as the Type, Chip, Id etc which can sometimes help identify exactly what it is. A 0 RPM fan reading could be there is no fan, no support for fan RPM reading (either by the fan or motherboard) or a broken fan.

Comment: @CharlesGreen  yes sir, I ran  `sudo sensors-detect`

Comment: @codlord sir, is that much of temperature (~111 deg Centigrade) acceptable ?

Comment: I can't say as I don't know what sensor it is. It could a false reading. If you run `sensors` in a command-line terminal it may show you readings as well as some `high` or `crit` values which may help you determine what is normal or not.

Comment: What driver did it install (look in `/etc/modules`)? Take the drivers that are there other than `coretemp` and look for it in `/etc/sensors3.conf` and post that section.